Server-sent events (SSE) using Python httpx-sse
I recently moved my API client code from requests to httpx. Meanwhile, the backend added SSE support that I would like to take advantage of.
I looked into the topic and the only thing I was able to find (in the context of httpx) is the httpx-sse  package. However, I am unable to get it to work.
I have an httpx.AsyncClient with the following configuration:

base_url - as I placeholde for this post I will use https://example.com/v2api

/data/sse - the path where SSEs can be retrieved from

headers - a dictionary in the form of
{
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'api-key' : 'test1234'
}

where the api-key is required for any REST operation

params - a dictionary in the form of
{
    'layerList' : 'test1,test2'
}

where the layerList represents a string of comma separated IDs of data structures I would like to "probe" for SSEs (in my case these are map layers).


I use the following code to check for SSEs. Due to a timeout with the SSE I had to set the client's timeout to None so that it runs indefinitely. That already indicated an issue...
client = httpx.AsyncClient(
    base_url='https://example.com/v2api',
    headers={
        'x-api-key' : 'test1234',
        'Content-type' : 'application/json'
        },
    timeout=None)

try:
    async with httpx_sse.aconnect_sse(client, 'GET', '/data/sse') as event_source:
        events = [sse async for sse in event_source.aiter_sse()]
        print(events)
except httpx.ReadTimeout as hrt:
    print(hrt)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

Note: The client works with other endpoints of the same API that are not SSE.
I don't get any output in the console. I also tried creating a new client in the with statement and instead of setting the base_url (httpx automatically concatenates any url with the base_url of the client's instance) I just used the full one (in case the httpx-sse works in a different way) along with headers and parameters again set in that very statement. The outcome was the same.
I know that the SSE is working since I was able to get it to work with the sseclient:
from sseclient import SSEClient

events = SSEClient('https://example.com/v2api/data/sse', headers={
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
            'x-api-key' : config['credentials']['api-key']
         },
         params={'layerList':'S1-test1-78bbda5d-929c-497e-b212-86a33dfbc8ff'})
for event in events:
    print(event)


UPDATE:
Interestingly enough, it works with the non-async client from httpx-sse.
